# Is it allowed to take the total derivative of an infinitesimal, and is it equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

For instance, I start with this relation:

$$
s^2=x^2+y^2
$$

Taking the total derivative on each side, I get:

$$
2sds=2xdx+2ydy
$$

Can I take the total derivative a second like this:

$$
d[sds]=d[xdx]+d[ydy]\\
dsds+sd[ds]=dxdx+xd[dx]+dydy+yd[dy]\\
(ds)^2=(dx)^2+(dy)^2
$$

where $d[d[s]]=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are treating differentials as algebraic units, the second differential is not equal to zero.  You can think of it as a second-order infinitesimal, but it is not zero.  It can be represented as you did $\text{d}(\text{d}x)$, but it is more often represented as $d^2(x)$.

The total second differential is what you had before trying to simplify:

$$(\text{d}s)^2 + s\,\text{d}^2s = (\text{d}x)^2 + x\,\text{d}^2x + (\text{d}y)^2 + y\,\text{d}^2y$$

For more information on algebraically-manipulable higher-order differentials, see my paper "[Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials](https://www.academia.edu/37619039/Extending_the_Algebraic_Manipulability_of_Differentials)".